# Bulk move content from one category to another - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have a lot of content that I've imported into Drupal 7. Unfortunately it imported to the wrong category. Is there a way in Drupal or drush to bulk move that content from one taxonomy term to another? Or is it a simple matter of assigning the new taxonomy term to the content?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the machine name of the taxonomy term is 'field_content_category', you will find a table in the database named 'field_data_field_content_category'.

If the newly updated nodes have nid > 2000 and your new category's taxonomy id is 5,

Use a simple query like 
'update field_data_field_content_category set field_content_category_tid = 5 where entity_id>2000.

Then clear the cache in drupal. It will have all been changed. If it still doesnt work, try emptying the  field_cache table.

Hope this helps